# Which has more citric acid, lemon or lime?

Tags: citrus

Does lime or lemon have more citric acid?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice - Citrus is a type of tree that grows fruit, such as lemons and limes. Asking if one has more citrus doesn’t make sense. Maybe you meant citric acid? Or something else?

Comment: If you clarify what you mean, such as if citric acid is what you meant, you likely also need the indicate a location as some cultures do not distinguish between lemons and limes, considering them simply varieties of the same fruit, considering limes to simply be a green variety of lemon.  Even then, each fruit has a range of varieties with different characteristics making the question still unanswerable.

Comment: This question is probably answerable if confined to western grocery staples, and acidity.

Comment: Okay, I'm editing this to refer to citric acid, since that seems the most likely guess. user65387, if you meant something different, feel free to edit or just ask a new question. And @dlb, I think that we can safely assume this means the usual English/US definition of lemon/lime, given that the OP thinks they're different fruits. If the answer is that they both have decent ranges, and the ranges overlap, that's still an answer - it doesn't make the *question* unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

"Lemon juice and lime juice are rich sources of citric acid, containing 1.44 and 1.38 g/oz, respectively."

PENNISTON, K. L., NAKADA, S. Y., HOLMES, R. P., & ASSIMOS, D. G. (2008). Quantitative Assessment of Citric Acid in Lemon Juice, Lime Juice, and Commercially-Available Fruit Juice Products. Journal of Endourology / Endourological Society, 22(3), 567–570. http://doi.org/10.1089/end.2007.0304

[See also this Q&A](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46423/are-limes-and-lime-juice-more-acidic-than-lemons-and-lemon-juice) for additional relevant information.